# During handling of the above exception (authenticate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'), another exception occurred:

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, authentication, django-allauth

Now I'm working on a Django project. We are using `django-allauth` for the user registration.

When we try to login with the wrong password, if `Debug = True`, everything was ok; but if `Debug = False`, then the following exception happens:

```
During handling of the above exception (authenticate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'),
another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)

  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)

  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper

    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 133, in dispatch
    return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 79, in dispatch
    **kwargs)

  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 101, in post
    if form.is_valid():

  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 183, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors

  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()

  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 385, in full_clean
    self._clean_form()

  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 412, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()

  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py", line 159, in clean
    **credentials)

  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/adapter.py", line 483, in authenticate
    user = authenticate(request=request, **credentials)

  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/compat.py", line 52, in authenticate
    return authenticate(request=request, **credentials)

  File "/Volumes/data/Peak/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 77, in authenticate
    inspect.getcallargs(backend.authenticate, request=request, **credentials)

KeyError: 'request'
2018-06-19 17:44:54,697 "POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 160691
ERROR:django.server:"POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 160691
```

How can I fix that?

We are using python3.

Comment: With such a vague description and no code, we can only tell you equally vague things (like "you can solve this problem by debugging"). Post a [mcve].

Comment: django-allauth is a 3rd party package.

Comment: Here is my error log on the console. I tried to upload my web pages but I'm not allowed yet because my reputation is lower than 10. Would you please answer with that error log?    I just installed django-allauth and include it's url and  `url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),`

Comment: Again when I login with correct email and password, or `Debug==True`, then I don't get that error.

Comment: @DanielLee if you follow the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example link posted earlier, you'll see that it's recommended that you include a sample of your source code.

Comment: hey guys. django-allauth is 3rd party package and is all out-of-box. We can just use it by setting URL and overwriting. I have provided all info and I followed the rule. I figured it out myself. It's not the coding error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to upgrade Django version.
This is not the code error. Just Django version error.
Install `Django 1.11.4.`
It works.